# What is this unknown plant?

Tags: identification

I live in the south west VA and I cant seem to identify this plant [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like Abutilon theophrasti, commonly called velvet leaf.

Comment: Is it edible can the flower be eaten.

Comment: Definitely velvet leaf. Deadhead immediately - it reseeds viciously and your neighbors will NOT be pleased with you.

Comment: Welcome! You could greatly improve the post by adding a few “why’s” - what characterizes the plant, how does the reader recognize it and what distinguishes it from similar other plants? [answer] should also give you a few pointers and as for all new users, the [tour] and [help] are good ways to learn more about how the site works.